# How to write a more compact ANDed conditions with if statement?

Tags: rfid, loop

I'm working on the rfid module and found an example that do it well. But it has a long testing the 5 bytes of the rfid received bytes, and I've tried to write it in a more compact way.

I did it with a for loop, but how to AND the conditions of the if statement?

How to change this:

```
if(bt0[cnt-1] == rfid.serNum[0] &&
   bt1[cnt-1] == rfid.serNum[1] &&
   bt2[cnt-1] == rfid.serNum[2] &&
   bt3[cnt-1] == rfid.serNum[3] &&
   bt4[cnt-1] == rfid.serNum[4]){
   lcd.clear();
   lcd.print("card accepted");
   digitalWrite(green_led,HIGH);
   digitalWrite(red_led,LOW);
 }
 else{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.print("card denied");
    digitalWrite(green_led,LOW);
    digitalWrite(red_led,HIGH);
}
```

To something like this:

```
    for(byte i=0;i<MXCD;i++){
      if(bt[i] == rfid.serNum[i%5]){
        cnt++;
      }
    }
    if(cnt==5){
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("card accepted");
      digitalWrite(green_led,HIGH);
      digitalWrite(red_led,LOW);
      cnt = 0;
    }
    else{
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.print("card denied");
      digitalWrite(green_led,LOW);
      digitalWrite(red_led,HIGH);
      cnt = 0; 
    }
```

In this way, I did it with 'cnt' variable to count the number of successful matched bytes then test of the number is equal to 5.

Is there a better way than this one ?

Thanks for any comments or suggestions :)

Comment: Hint: There is a standard C function for this, `memcmp()`. You would use it like, `if (!memcmp(bt, rfid.serNum, 5)) ...`. Ref. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/

Comment: wow thanks !! this function actually isn't new to me, but I didn't thought of it and its usage at this situation ! thanks again man ..

Comment: @MikaelPatel you should post that as an answer so the OP can accept it.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Perch Eagle and @MikaelPatel, I want to learn something out of this question and your accepted answer, but I do not understand how it works. You write you want to compare elements of five different arrays (bt0[], bt1[], … bt4[]) with elements of one array (rfid.serNum[]). As an answer you are fine with a comparison with a new array bt[]. To make this work there must be a relation between bt[] and bt0[], bt1[], … bt4[]. Where in your sketch is this done or is this naturally but only I cannot understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard C function for this, `memcmp()`. It performs a memory block compare and can be used like this:

```
if (!memcmp(bt, rfid.serNum, sizeof(bt))) {
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("card accepted");
  digitalWrite(green_led,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(red_led,LOW);    
} 
else {
  ...
}
```

Ref. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/

Comment: Yep, it works perfectly! Thank you dude ..